# Add trailing slash to directory urls even if directory dont exist in Apache

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have created a sort of AWS S3 proxy PHP script, which hides a lot of files behind username/password.

My problem is that directory-like urls has to have trailing slash appended for links in the html files to work.
Ex: foo.com/link should rewrite to foo.com/link/

File urls should still be file urls.
Ex: foo.com/folder/image.png -> foo.com/folder/image.png

I have found lots of Apache mod_rewrite rules like this

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1/ [R=301,L]
```

But `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f` depends on the actual requested folder to exist on the server. And since i do fetch the actual folders and files from AWS S3 it fails.

My current .htaccess
    RewriteEngine on

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond $1 !^(redirect\.php|test\.php|css)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ redirect.php?file=$1 [L]
```

Has anybody had this issue before and found a solution?

Extended info: I have implemented automatic add of index.html, index.htm, default.php ect. in the redirect.php-scriot for folder-like urls to work. But the static links in the HTML is broken if the trailing slash is not added.

Comment: If you can explain in English how you'd determine whether a URL is directory-like, I can tell you how phrase it in mod_rewrite.

Comment: I my mind a url like /folder or /folder/ is a directory. They key point is (for this project) is there is a file-extension ex. /folder/file.ext.